# React onClick not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following code doesn't work. The `onClick` events are never fired but I see no errors in browserify or console.

```
var React = require('react');

var Button = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="Button">
        <span className="left" onclick={function() {alert("left")}}>Left</span>
        <span className="right" onclick={function() {alert("right")}}>Right</span>
        <span className="middle" onclick={function() {alert("middle")}}>Middle</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports=Button;
```

I use alert just for testing small CSS. Why isn't onclick firing?

Comment: did you try with onClick instead of onclick ?

Comment: please create fiddle

Comment: Also `alert.bind(this,"left")` doesnot work

Comment: Try `alert.bind(window, 'left');`. alert is a function of the window object. Calling it in another scope might have unexpected effects since it is a native method

Comment: Somehow alert.bind didnot work in browserify/reactify but worked in JSFiddle so I reverted to original question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a typo in your example. Use 'onClick' instead of 'onclick'.

```
<span className="left" onClick={function() {alert("left")}}>Left</span>
```

see jsfiddle for a working example - https://jsfiddle.net/Ltdc8qpr/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here with arrow function syntax, triggering the event with onClick handler.

```
<span className="left" onClick={() => {alert("left")}}>Left</span>
```

Comment: this is not recommended by lint rule jsx-no-lambda

Comment: @devi, Appreciate your thought and rule. You define your own linter as per need, it doesn't mean lambda is not allowed in calling of event handler of javascript. Even while passing the props from child to parent on ONclick handler we need to pass as


Child Invocation
`onClick={() => this.props.callingFunction(passingdata)}`

OnParent
`<SomeClass callingFunction={this.callingFunction}>`

`callingFunction = (passedData) => {
  // dealing 
}`
Much simple 
Let me know if any. Its easy nothing major :)

Comment: @maurya ,this is public not my rule 
if you need pass data to handler, then bind it before to highr-order func like this:
const bindData = () => (data) => this.props.callingFunction(data)
then set in jsx without lambdas

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The problem was that the `<span>` tag was in the top-left corner and the alert would only fire when I would click the top-left corner. Not any other space.

I changed `<span>` to `<div>` and it worked.